# c# app to sync calendar with exchange server?

Tags: c#, synchronization, calendar, exchange-server

we have a costume calendar system based on oracle database

our Oracle Gurus created a web-service that we can use to add/edit/read from our calendar system

to make it more clear:
it should be like if an event was added to Exchange then it will be sent to our calendar and if it was add to our calendar then it will be sent to the exchange server, and sync any changes!

what is the best way to do that?
I can do C# , but the problem that I can not find a "start point" that!

I was thinking to create a service that sync the data, but is there other ways?
I do not want to use a code with Outlook, because some people may be away and uses only mobile phone, so it has to communicate directly with exchange!

any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after searching I found out I can do that in different ways :-)

the best as I saw is to use Exchange Web Services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

do not forget to download http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1 and use the dll (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll) in your Visual Studio Project

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
```

have fun ;-)

Comment: So how did you solve it? I have a similar problem, and it would be very helpful if you could add a few pointers to your answer. :)

Comment: well you can do it in 2 ways, simply using SOAP messages from your app, if your app is C# based then it is even easier, with Exchange Web Services Managed API , just use the build in functions :-)

Comment: Both of these links are now dead.

Answer (score 6):

The EWS managed API is a good starting point. Additionally, if you want some event-like notifications for changes happening at the Exchange server, have a look at http://exchangenotification.codeplex.com/. I've created a .NET wrapper that simplifies using Exchange Push/Pull notifications in your own applications.